# How to update the template when Ngrx state chnages with out async pipe?

Tags: angular, ngrx, angular10

is there a way to update the Html template when Ngrx state changes with out using async pipe.
The reason for not using async, i need to add some logic based on changed Ngrx state.

i know one method that is

```
ngOnInit(){
    this.store.select(selectDeletePhoneNumberError).subscribe((data) => {
      if (data) {
        // update the html data
      }
    });
}
```

but ngOnInit runs only if the component renders/re-renders.

Comment: A subscription emitting a new value triggers a change detection cycle, so subscribing like you are should already be updating the template. Could you clarify what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: If you're consuming the state in your component and just need a side effect, you can [`tap`](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/tap) the stream. Leave the `AsyncPipe` in the template and add your additional logic in the `tap`.

Comment: @DM you mean we need both async pipe and ngOnint. inside ngOnint we need to tap before subscription ?

i did not get you

Comment: If you're already using the `AsyncPipe` in the template and you just need to produce a side effect when the stream emits, you can use `tap`. If you're not using the `AsyncPipe` in the template, you can subscribe in `ngOnInit` like you're doing an each time the stream emits, it will trigger a change detection cycle for your component which will update the template. Please clarify what you're trying to do and what your component/template code looks like right now. There's not enough information to provide an answer.

Answer (score 0):

The best is to use async pipe and to put the additional logic in the Reducer or Effect that returning the data.
If you need more details just write more about the Reducers and Effects.